# Как правильно отобразить картинку, зная ее ширину, высоту и dpi?

Tags: javascript, css, dpi

Имеется двумерный массив - битмап - представляющий собой картинку. То есть набор пикслей. Каждый пиксель кодируется 3 байтами - RGB. Например это `ImageData` для `Canvas`. Известны следующие параметры: width, height и dpi изображения. 
Просто все это отобразить на canvas несложно.

Однако вот частный случай: width = 5100, height = 6600 и dpi = 600.

То есть картинка весьма большая сама по себе и тут предполагается ее уменьшение. 
Не силен в данной теме, но как понял, надо делать следующее.

1. Определить ppi монитора (как я понимаю грамотнее говорить ppi), например 96.
2. Найти отношение dpi картинки к ppi монитора, например 600/96 = 6,25.
3. Поделить ширину и высоту картинки на полученное отношение. То есть 5100 / 6,25 = 816, 6600 / 6,25 = 1056.
4. Отобразить картинку в сжатом виде с новой шириной и высотой.

Есть вопрос -  как определить ppi монитора. Почитав в сети по этой теме некоторые источники, я пришел к выводу, что наиболее простой способ - это создать элемент с шириной '1in', а потом запросить его `offsetWidth`. Однако этот способ не всегда работает.

Вообщем то теперь вопросы:

1. Правильно ли я понимаю правила отрисовки изображений? (отношения ppi и dpi, сжатие картинки и т.д.)
2. Есть ли какие то еще способы определения ppi? Читал про медиа запросы, но как понял это css и не разобрался как через js получить эту инфу. Если кто сможет подробно обяъяснить, буду весьма благодарен.
3. Как сжимать картинку? Вот есть исходная высота и ширина, а надо получить в сжатом виде. Как обойти массив пикселей и что с ними сделать?

Comment: а вы хотите картинку размером, например, 10 см показать на экране тоже на 10 см ?

Comment: @splash58 не понял вопроса. Пока что я хочу у себя на мониторе в нормальном размере картику показать, а не в 6 раз  шире. Я как сказал не силен в правилах отображения картинок с учетом dpi.

Comment: тогда не очень понятно, почему так сложно. у вас же есть размер в пикселях области на которую отображать и размер картинки в пикселях. вот с ними и работайте. зачем вам dpi. Он нужен только в том случае, если вы хотите пересчитать размер картинки в дюймы, мм и тд

Comment: @splash58 Ну скажем так, я хочу отобразить картинку в "100%", как оно задумывалось при ее кодировании. Это как вот при просмотре pdf или djvu масштаб так сказать. Но ваша мысль верна, по поводу размеров области отображения - могу и без этого обойтись по началу, хотя и хочу узнать что и как. Но меня интересует все же вопрос как сжимать картинку.

Comment: смотрите. dpi говорит следующее - при выводе разместите столько-то пикселей на 1 дюйм. Если вы хотите сохранять геометрию, то да, он вам нужен и вам нужно знать плотность точек монитора. А если это не важно, то про канвас я ничего не понимаю, но атрибут width у img прекрасно масштабирует картинку. Наверное, я плохо объясняю, но пока я не понял, зачем вам dpi

Comment: @splash58 ну да идея с img тоже верна. Можно содержимое `canvas` закодировать в dataURL и отображать потом картинку с другими размерами. Хотя я бы хотел и через сырой массив вручную это попробовать, так как на холсте больше возможностей. Ну а по поводу dpi - да хочу сохранять геометрию, так что по вашим же словам, он мне нужен (хотя и не всегда).